# CSS wont render with Rocker.rs

Tags: css, rust, rust-rocket

Im trying to serve some CSS to my webapp using rocket.rs but it doesn't seem to render

This is what I've tried so far and when i spin up the web app i can access localhost:8000/style.css and it does exist however it just doesn't render

```rust
#[get("/style.css")]
fn serve_css() -> &'static str {
    r#"
.notes {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.notes li {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    margin: 1em;
    background: #ffb;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.notes li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff #fff #eea #eea;
    background: #eea;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
    "#
```

I have got the sylesheet linked at the top of my html body

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the return type to RawCSS and return RawCSS instead of just a string